# FATAL: No bootable found! system halted. VirtualBox error

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

I finally finished the problem about virtual technology, so I tried to run the machine but then this popped up:

[image]

Comment: Does `eeee` have an image associated with it? If so, has the path to the `.vdi` changed? i.e. have you moved the virtual machine image to another drive? Also, check the boot order on the `eeee` VM, make sure it's not still looking for an `.iso` image.

Comment: I don't mean to sound strict, but did you at least *try* to read a bit about what Virtual Box does before asking this question? It's a bit like rushing to buy a new car, then asking "what's that round thing in front of me?". No DV, respecting your new user status, but you're much more likely to get answers *useful to you* if you make some effort yourself. All the best :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you make and install a Virtual Machine? Like Ubuntu?  It does not look like it.

Get an ISO for a virtual machine you wish to run. Ubuntu is a good first choice .

Go to the Ubuntu site, download a current version of Ubuntu and save it.

Go to Virtual Box, open it, and make a new machine. Point to the ISO file you saved and follow the machine creation prompts.

Make sure you understand what Virtual Box will do.

If you think you already created a machine, make sure you know where it is and point Virtual Box to this machine.

Comment: i don't know which to install, there are 4 apps: Ubuntu server, Ubuntu cloud, ubuntu flavors, Ubuntu for IoT

Comment: You want Ubuntu Desktop (not Server).   .....  https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Comment: how do i point it?

Comment: Open Virtual Box.   File, Open (check VBOX for the exact Command) and in File, Open, use the navigation window to locate the machine (assuming you made a machine and saved it).

Comment: Do you mean on panels?

Comment: Yes. Any time you open a file a dialogue opens and that can be called many things.  I use VMware Workstation but I have use VBOX. I am typing this in a Linux virtual machine.

Comment: I don't have VBOX, I just downloaded Virtual Box

Comment: VBOX is just an Acronym for Virtual Box. I mean Virtual Box.

Comment: I don't see open in panels

Comment: Try this Oracle link for opening / importing a machine. .....  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26217_01/E26796/html/qs-import-vm.html

Comment: I just have oracle VM virtual box manager, I don't have anything else

Comment: Oracle makes Virtual Box and the document I pointed to shows how to manage Virtual Box and your question shows Virtual Box.